# how to programmatically change a variable in a python package to run test

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a project structure something like this. I want to write a test which programmatically change **version** variable in myPackage/version.py and write a test in tests/unit/test_release.py.

```
├── myPackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── root.py
│   └── version.py
└── tests
    └── unit
        └── test_release.py
```

cat myPackage/**init**.py

```
from .version import __version__
```

cat myPackage/root.py

```
from .version import __version__
def printFunc():
  return __version__

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(printFunc())
```

cat myPackage/version.py

```
__version__ = '5.7.11'
```

cat tests/unit/test_release.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/username/myfolder")

from myPackage import root, version
import unittest

class TestHelp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_version(self):
      version.__version__ = '7.8.19'
      new_version = root.printFunc()
      assert new_version == '7.8.19'
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this for now.

```
from importlib import reload

class TestHelp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_version(self):
      myPackage.version.__version__ = '7.8.19'
      myPackage.root = reload(myPackage.root)
      new_version = myPackage.root.printFunc()
      assert new_version == '7.8.19'
```